# Android Bluetooth Low Energy code compatible with API>=21 AND API<21

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an app that have to connect with a BLE device, in my code I want to use the new Scan and ScanCallback for BLE implemented from API 21 (Android 5) but I have to maintain the compatibility with Android 4.3 and above.

So I wrote the code, for example, in this way:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        } else {
            btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        }
```

And I have defined the 2 callbacks, one for API 21 and above and one for API 18 to 20:

```
    //API 21
private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
              BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
              connectToDevice(btDevice);
         }
         public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
              if (mGatt == null) {
                   mGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, btleGattCallback);
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                   } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                   }
               }
         }
    };


//API 18 to 20
        private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

        btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, btleGattCallback);
            }
        });


    }
};
```

I also added the annotation

```
@TargetApi(21)
```

but when I launch the App on Android 4.x it crashes immediately reporting the error that the class ScanCallback cannot be found (the one intended to be used only with Android 5 and above).

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much.
Daniele.

Comment: Could you show us the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 7):

After reading several posts I did the following. Just in case, here is the documentation of Android about [BluetoothLe](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

**First**

Create two methods one `scanLeDevice21` and `scanLeDevice18`. On `scanLeDevice21` add the annotation `@RequiresApi(21)` that says:

> Denotes that the annotated element should only be called on the given API level or higher.
>   This is similar in purpose to the older @TargetApi annotation, but more clearly expresses that this is a requirement on the caller, rather than being used to "suppress" warnings within the method that exceed the minSdkVersion.

**Second**

Implement each method, here's my code.

```
@RequiresApi(21)
private void scanLeDevice21(final boolean enable) {

    ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = result.getDevice();

            if (!bluetoothDeviceList.contains(bluetoothDevice)) {
                Log.d("DEVICE", bluetoothDevice.getName() + "[" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress() + "]");
                bluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter.add(bluetoothDevice);
                bluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results);

        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        }
    };

    final BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
            mScanning = false;
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}


 /**
 * Scan BLE devices on Android API 18 to 20
 *
 * @param enable Enable scan
 */
private void scanLeDevice18(boolean enable) {

    BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            bluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter.add(bluetoothDevice);
                            bluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }

}
```

**Third**

Every time you need to scan devices you surround your code asking which version you are. For instance, I have a `RefreshLayout` to display the list of devices. Here's the result:

```
  /**
 * Refresh listener
 */
private void refreshScan() {
    if (!hasFineLocationPermissions()) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);


        //Up to marshmallow you need location permissions to scan bluetooth devices, this method is not here since is up to you to implement it and it is out of scope of this question. 
        requestFineLocationPermission();

    } else {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            scanLeDevice21(true);
        } else {
            scanLeDevice18(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it.

Forget about extending, subclassing classes you don't really need like ulusoyca answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, worked great and is really simple to implement

Comment: @Pedro thanks for your efforts in putting this solution. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create `AbstractBluetoothLe` class and `IBleScanCallback` interface. `IBleScanCallback` interface is a Marker Interface. In other saying, an interface with no methods. You can also add methods to interface if you need. These methods will do the same functionality for all type of scanCallbacks i.e. getListOfFoundBleDevices(), clearListOfFoundBleDevices() etc.
2. Create `BluetootLeLollipop`, and `BluetoothLeJellyBean` classes which extend `AbstractBluetoothLe` class. Create also `BluetootLeMarshmallow` class which extends `BluetootLeLollipop`class. `AbstractBluetoothLe` class has protected field `mIBleScanCallback` which is an `IBleScanCallback` object.
3. Create `BleScanCallbackBase` class which implements `IBleScanCallback`.
4. Create `LollipopScanCallback` class which extends `ScanCallback` class and implements `IBleScanCallback` interface. .This class has a protected field `scanCallback` which will be instantiated as `BleScanCallbackBase` object. Create also `MarshmallowScanCallback` class which extends `LollipopScanCallback` class.
5. Create `JellyBeanScanCallback` class which extends `BleScanCallbackBase` and implements `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback`
6. In `BleScanCallbackBase` override the method: `onScanCallback(...)`
7. In `LollipoScanCallback` override `onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result)` and inside this method call the method `onScanCallback(...)` of the `scanCallback` object.
8. In `JellyBeanScanCallback` override `onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)` and inside this method call `onScanCallback(...)`
9. Finally, do whatever needs to be done when a device is found in `onScanCallback(...)`method of `BleScanCallbackBase` class.

In short, read about composition over inheritance- I know this is not an answer to your question but this is a neat way of what you want to achieve in the end. Here is the class diagram: [image]

Comment: In order to extend `ScanCallback` the API minimum has to be 21, which means excluding all devices lower than Jellybean. Is it possible to change an Android Studio gradle build to allow API level 21+ functionality if the device is capable?

Comment: @0x6 Yes you are right. I updated my answer accordingly. Please check again.

Comment: Please answer the question or do not reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing because it is creating anonymous inner class. Hence at run time it doesn't find that sCanCallback class.

Try below way and share the outcome. Before you try this, make sure you comment the callback(ScanCallback).

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
              BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
              connectToDevice(btDevice);
         }
         public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
              if (mGatt == null) {
                   mGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, btleGattCallback);
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                   } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                   }
               }
         }
    };
        } else {
            btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my idea to overcome this crash on devices below API 21. The `ScanCallback` class has support from API 21. So when you write a code to implement ScanCallback in your scan code it will cause a crash on lover APIs. I have fixed it the following way:

I created one new abstract class which extending ScanCallback class as follows:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)  
public abstract class AppScanCallback extends ScanCallback {}
```

Now I am using this class instance in my BluetoothService class as follow:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private AppScanCallback mScanCallback;
```

And using this variable as follow:

```
public void startBleScan() {
    if (isEnabled()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            _bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner = _bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .build();
            filters = new ArrayList<>();

            mScanCallback = new AppScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
                        onLeScanResult(btDevice, result.getScanRecord().getBytes());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                    for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                        Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                    Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
                }
            };
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        }

    }
}
```

and to stop scan

```
public void stopBLEScan() {;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            _bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
}
```

Hope it will help you out.